# Write Batch class ,if contact's Phone field have only 4 or 5 digit so append 0 digit up to 10?

Tags: apex, batch

```
public class BatchContactPhone implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.stateful{
    public integer  i = 0; 
    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        return Database.getQueryLocator('Select id, Phone from Contact');
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> conList){
        if(!conList.isEmpty()){
            for(Contact objCon : conList){
                if(String.valueOf(objCon.Phone).length() <= 10){
                    String count = String.valueOf(objCon.Phone).length();
                    
                    for(String i = 0; count <= 10; i++){
                        //  Num = 10 - objCon.Phone.length(); 
                    }
                }
            }
            Database.update(conList, false);
        }
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SFSE! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Right now, this isn't a question (you have a requirement and a code dump). You need to [edit] your question to give us more details and point to a specific and narrow thing that you're have trouble with.

Comment: General advice: Look through the methods of [the String Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm) to see if there's anything that might help you achieve the thing you're trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (exploit the `repeat()` method of [String class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.232.0.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_methods_system_string.htm#unique_1029097006))

```
public void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Contact> conList){

   for(Contact objCon : conList){
       if (String.IsBlank(objCon.Phone) {continue;}
       objCon.Phone = '0'.repeat(10-objCon.Phone.length()) + objCon.Phone;
            
   }
   Database.update(conList, false);
}
```

**Notes**

1 - there's no need to check for the `execute()` method being passed an empty list; the for loop will just do 0 iterations and a batch job will never pass an empty list to an `execute()`.

2 - You can optimize the DML by managing a separate list of Contacts that actually need padding

Answer (score 0):

Your code is having for-loop inside a for-loop. This can be avoided by using collection variables which will make your code more efficient.

You can create a map like -

```
Map<Integer, String> differenceMap = new Map<Integer, String> {
    0 => '',
    1 => '0',
    2 => '00',
    3 => '000',
    // follow same as above till 10
}
```

After doing this you can replace your inside for loop like this -

```
objCon.Phone += differenceMap.get(10 - objCon.Phone.length());
```

Just make sure to put in some checks before executing the above line.

If objCon.Phone.length() gives error then convert it to string.